# MySql Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting a weird error that I don't understand, I tried everything but nothing worked,  here is my request:

```
public function displayFirstEvents_indexed($start, $limit)
    {
        $query = $this->connect()->prepare(
            "SELECT *
            FROM t_event join t_type_event using(tte_id)
            WHERE eve_active = :active AND tte_lib = :lib
            ORDER BY eve_date DESC
            LIMIT :start, :limit;"
        );
        $query->bindParam(':start', $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->bindParam(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->execute([':active' => 'yes', ':lib' => 'first']);
        return $query;
    }
```

here is the error

```
    <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xampp\htdocs\UFTAM WEBSITE API\classes\event.c.php:105
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\UFTAM WEBSITE API\classes\event.c.php(105): PDOStatement-&gt;execute(Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\UFTAM WEBSITE API\handers\events\displayFirstEvents_indexed.php(7): Event-&gt;displayFirstEvents_indexed('1', '4')
#2 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\UFTAM WEBSITE API\classes\event.c.php</b> on line <b>105</b><br />
```

I tried replacing ':active' and ':lib' with '?' but it gave me the same error, does anyone know a solution for this ?

I suspect the problem here is in the Where close I think I cant use 'where' with 'limit' I've been looking into it and I haven't found any example with 'where' and 'limit' together, does anyone think that this is true?

Comment: I don't think you can mix `bindParam()` and `execute([..])` in that way. Though I never tried :-)

Comment: well I figured as much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A note I found on php.net from 10 years ago:

> Note that you must

- EITHER pass all values to bind in an array to PDOStatement::execute()
- OR bind every value before with PDOStatement::bindValue(), then call PDOStatement::execute() with *no* parameter (not even "array()"!).
  Passing an array (empty or not) to execute() will "erase" and replace any previous bindings (and can lead to, e.g. with MySQL, "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031" (CR_PARAMS_NOT_BOUND) if you passed an empty array).

https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

As frustrating as this may be (because why not!?), you cannot mix 'bind' and 'execute' when using PDO. Two of your parameters are being deleted. Either pass the tokens in the execute, or bind them all first. (I'd probably bind them first and in order.)

```
$query->bindValue(':active', 'yes', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(':lib', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(':start', $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindValue(':limit', 'first', PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
```

If binding doesn't work, try putting them into the execute (). If you do this though, be mindful of PHP PDO apparent issue with limit.

https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#limit

Comment: but I have another problem if you can help me with it if you can. When the limit reach length-1 the last data is not being retrieved from the database I don't know why, but I'm getting 2 rows each time the user clicks on the loading button, here is an example [check me](http://newsite.uftam.net/uftam_actuality)

Answer (score 1):

The order of the mysql command are wrong, ORDER BY is behind the WHERE Clause

```
$query = $this->connect()->prepare(
        "SELECT *
        FROM t_event join t_type_event using(tte_id)            
        WHERE eve_active = :active AND tte_lib = :lib
        ORDER BY eve_date DESC
        LIMIT  :start,:limit;"
    );
    $sth->bindValue(':active', 'yes', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindValue(':lib', 'first', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindValue(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->bindValue(':start', $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
```

And bind all 4 variables before executing.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference=>it's at the ':active position'

Comment: any idea on how to fix this one ?

Comment: still giving me the same error( Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference)

Comment: and btw the order for the offset and limit is not wrong

Comment: As you are trying to bind a literal - change `bindParam` to `bindValue`

Comment: It may be worth correcting the error `('':lib'` which has an extra `'`

Comment: can you tell me more about this bindValue change ? how does it work? what's the difference?

Comment: are you sure that you have pdo and not mysql, that error message looks more liike a mysqli error where it would klook more like $stmt->bind_param('sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent); , which would account for the string value

Comment: I'm very sure that I know what am working with and it's PDO @nbk

Comment: I suspect  the problem here is in the Where close I think I cant use 'where' with 'limit' I've been looking into it and I haven't found any example with 'where' and 'limit' together, does anyone think that this is true?